# Array de frases em Java

Tags: java, android

Estou estudando Java, e desenvolvimento Android, e quero fazer esta aplicação para entender como funciona.

Estou utilizando a classe Toast para que ao clicar na imagem, apareça uma frase, consegui fazer funcionar com números, mas no lugar dos números quero colocar algumas frases e quando eu clicar em cima da imagem, a frase apareça por alguns segundos na tela.

Como faço isso sem muitas alterações neste código que ja tenho?

```
    package android.tutorial.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

// public void mostrarMensagem(View view) {
    //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.sorteia(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    //toast.show();

  //}


 public void mostrarMensagem(View view) {
     int[] lista = new int[]
             {
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
             };
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i : lista)
     {
          builder.append("" + i + " ");
     }
     Toast.makeText(this, builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      }


}
```

[image: Array com Toast]

Comment: Não entendi por que do *array* de frases, pois se quiser exibir somente uma frase basta trocar a variável `builder` dentro do `Toast` por uma string. É isso?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues O que Eu quero é que a cada clique apareça uma mensagem diferente!

Comment: @PauloRodrigues com este código abaixo, se eu cadastrar 5 mensagens no array e der um unico toque na tela irão aparecer as 5 mesnagens, uma seguida  da outra e não é isso que eu quero. 1 toque, 1 mensagem.                                                    String [] arr = new String []{"sentence one", "sentence two"};
  for(String str : arr)
      Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça algo assim:

```
public void mostrarMensagem(View view) {
    String[] lista = new String []{"sentence one", "sentence two"};
    String randomStr = lista[new Random().nextInt(lista.length)];

    Toast.makeText(this, randomStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Lembrando que não há nenhuma regra de não poder repetir a frase, para isso teria que fazer algo mais.

Comment: Por hora era isso mesmo que Eu queria, vai me servir como base de estudos, vou entender estes códigos ai. Se não for abusar muito, você pode me dar o caminho das pedras para evitar a repetição das frases? Muitissimo obrigado pela ajuda!